# Есть ли бесплатные API сервисы автозаполнения адреса?

Tags: vue.js, autocomplete

Нужно сделать на VueJS input с автодополнением города. К примеру, ввожу в поле "Мос" и там появляются варианты Москва, Мосальск и тд. Любые советы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Возьмите Классификатор Адресов России с сайта налоговой, залейте себе в БД и реализуйте сами.

Раздел сайта со ссылками на актуальные версии: https://fias.nalog.ru/Updates

Рекомендую использовать формат КЛАДР 4.0, он проще чем ФИАС

Comment: Это самый простой вариант. На прошлой работе нужно было такое сделать и сделали именно так. Подгрузить несколько килобайт джейсона клиенту не беда.